# how do i share my mobile internet connection via wifi in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-touch, internet, 3g, sharing

Newbie here. I am trying to use share my 3g mobile internet connection but don't know how to do this. Any working ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Just turn on tethering option on your mobile.And then connect your pc with the mobile via wifi.

Answer (score -1):

> In short the steps are:
>
> - Verify: WIFI card can support "master mode" or act as an Access    Point.
> - Install: You will need hostapd, isc-dhcp-server, firestarter.
> - Config: Do some configuration edits on those packages.
> - Script: Run a script that starts everything.
> - Firewall: Start firestarter to connect the Wifi Access Point to the    3G data card.
> - Trouble Shooting: Extra info if you are stuck
> - Starting/Stopping: How to start and stop once it works

More details and how to configure can be found [here](http://www.svsarana.com/share_3G_data_internet_over_wifi.php?redirect=1)